# Flutter HTTP GET Request doesn't hit backend endpoint at all

Tags: flutter, dart, httprequest

I'm trying to make a **GET** request to my local backend server using the `http` package, here is the code below:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';

class MyApi {

  static Future<List> myFunction() async {
    String url = 'http://myhost/api/myendpoint';

    http.Response response = await http.get(url);

    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

}
```

I've used this code in this same codebase and it works perfectly. It's just this one endpoint that fails.

I've used a `debugPrint()` to print the response, but it returns with nothing.

I've even tried throwing an exception on the backend to see if the response would reflect that exception, but nothing at all.

The endpoint works on Postman.

---

**UPDATE**

Turns out the code was failing at `json.decode(response.body)` for some reason.

I printed out `response.body` without decoding and got this response (as expected):

```
{
    "title":
    [
        {
            "title":"A title",
            "id":1,
            "description":"A description"
        },
        {
            "title":"A title 2",
            "id":2,
            "description":"A description 2"
        },
    ]
}
```

But I need to decode the response.

Comment: did you print out the statusCode from response?

Comment: @OldProgrammer - It returns a 200 status code

Comment: @OldProgrammer - Turns out the `response.body` failed to decode, but the response cam back successfully.